# What is the exact difference between error and residual?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

because what I am thinking is residual=(actual - predicted). Let's take linear regression actual function:

`y= mx+c+error`, what function we are getting in prediction is `y=mx+c` by

minimizing RSS. Then residual is nothing but error then why these 2 terms described as different.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There can be variants in the definitions, we can't answer you without more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all practical purposes, and in a *machine learning* context, these two terms are treated as synonyms.

The term "residual" is due to the origins of linear regression from *statistics*; since the term "error" in statistics had (has) a different meaning that in today's ML, a different term was needed to declare the difference between the estimated (predicted) values of a dependent variable and its observed ones, hence the "residual".

You can find more details in the Wikipedia entry for [Errors and residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals) (notice the plural); quoting:

> In statistics and optimization, **errors** and **residuals** are two closely related and easily confused measures of the deviation of an observed value of an element of a statistical sample from its "theoretical value". The **error** (or **disturbance**) of an observed value is the deviation of the observed value from the (unobservable) true value of a quantity of interest (for example, a population mean), and the **residual** of an observed value is the difference between the observed value and the estimated value of the quantity of interest (for example, a sample mean). The distinction is most important in regression analysis, where the concepts are sometimes called the **regression errors** and **regression residuals** and where they lead to the concept of studentized residuals.

Keep in mind that the above come from the statistics realm; in a ML context, we use the term "error" (singular) to mean the difference between predicted and observed values, and the term "residual(s)" is practically almost never used ...

Comment: In linear regression, we are using the sample mean. Is my consideration is right that after minimizing we are getting residual as (actual - predicted) is the same as the error in y=mx+c+error? thanks in advance.

Comment: @AKash_KUmar yes, you could say that

Answer (score -1):

Error: is the difference from the **expected value** (based on the whole population).

Residual: is the **estimate** of the unobservable statistical error. You can consider the residual as estimates of the errors.

Basically, the residuals is what you can actually deal with having estimated your model.